# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass when signin user in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application after `sign in` user I want to show user `name` and `email` on the other page:

below is session's controller page:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

    def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
            sign_in user
            redirect_to '/mail'
        else
            flash[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
            sign_out
            redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

and below is my `mail` page where I want to show user `name` and `email`:

```
<%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
```

But I am getting below error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Below is `routes` page:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/home"
  get "users/new"
  resources  :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root "static_pages#home"
  match '/signup',  to:'users#new',           via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',       via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',   via: 'delete'
  match '/mail',    to: 'static_pages#mails', via: 'get'
end
```

below is the `logs`:

```
Started POST "/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-03 02:32:27 -0700
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cE+KbuathFhdhvhLcmxo7IGVEha1s7SgUk5HiU/qBD0=", "session"=>{"email"=>"hassan@ali.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'hassan@ali.com' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `remember_token`
  [1m[36mSQL (12.0ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "remember_token" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 1[0m  [["remember_token", "a5363dd5d9c4b0b45e5405d01c8d20a8b76d2dac"], ["updated_at", Wed, 03 Sep 2014 09:32:27 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (87.0ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/mail
Completed 302 Found in 196ms (ActiveRecord: 100.0ms)
```

This is my session helper:

```
module SessionsHelper

    def sign_in(user)
        remember_token = User.new_remember_token
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
        self.current_user = user
    end

    def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    def current_user=(user)
        @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
        remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
    end

    def sign_out
        current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,
                                  User.digest(User.new_remember_token))
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
        self.current_user = nil
    end
end
```

Kindly help me, waiting for reply.

Thanks.

Comment: where is the other page
?

Comment: the other page is `mail` page.

Comment: show it and issue is at where you have set `@user` object.

Comment: `<%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>` these lines on my `mail` page, that I have already show you

Comment: Are you sure you get redirected to `mail` page? Because you'd have the same error if your session creation was unsuccessful and `create` action rendered `new` template. You should have `@user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)` in controller and modify the rest of `create` action accordingly.

Comment: yes, @user is nil, but I don't understand why?

Comment: yes, I want to redirect to `mail` page

Comment: Ok, show relevant logs part.

Comment: Where is the `mail` action?

Comment: Right, you should also show `static_pages#email` action.

Comment: you need to dig more in how your user is getting set in session that why its nil...check the create action which is not setting up the user.

Comment: I am getting user at this line `@user = User.find(params[:id])` in the sessions controller that I show you, but `@user` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should modify the `SessionsController` to avoid this error on unsuccessful login attempt:

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to '/mail'
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Second thing, if you need to show current user's name and email on `mail` page, you should probably use `current_user` helper:

```
<%= current_user.name %>, <%= current_user.email %>
```

Comment: `<%= current_user.name %>, <%= current_user.email %>` its not show me user `name` and `email`

Comment: @user88 Are you sure you're signed in? What do you use for authentication? Devise, or your own code? If the latter, show me `current_user` source.

Comment: @user88 check what does `current_user` return in `mail` action when you're signed in.

Comment: `current_user` is empty

Comment: @user88 if it's empty, `mail` action should raise exception. Does it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60444/discussion-between-user88-and-marek-lipka).